# What's the difference between bundle names and Apple App store names?

Tags: iphone, bundle

Does an app's bundle name must match the name in the Apple App store? For instance, for Angry Birds, there is "Angry Birds" and "Angry Birds Seasons" in the app store, however when installed on the device, the names of both apps are displayed as "Angry Birds".

Any suggestions? Thanks.

Comment: David, technically they do not have to be the same string.  By the way you can simply try this when you build during development!! The name under the icon can be anything. **However** Note that **Apple will require you to make them very similar**.  We had one update of a product rejected because on that version the bundle display name under the icon was some witty joke, instead of something actually literally similar to the legal App Name.  In a word, **Apple will reject your submission** if they are not very close. Hope it helps!

Answer (score 9, accepted):

No, a bundle name doesn't need to match the App Store name. The main reason for this is you only get between 11-14ish characters for your app name on device before it gets clipped by the system. On the app store this limitation doesn't exist. In your main app .plist file your app name (the name that displays under your icon) is you bundle display name. Bundle display names do not need to be unique (hence why Angry Birds Seasons & Angry Birds both use 'Angry Birds' as their display names), but your app store name obviously does!

Answer (score 2):

And since January 2012, the app store name does *not* have to be unique. It only needs to be unique for a particular language, even though an app can appear on all the different app stores in the world. More information on my blog post: http://hacknicity.com/post/18128530922/whats-in-an-app-name

Answer (score 1):

...all right in "ixt" answer, i just wanted to add that "Bundle display name" not only doesn't need to be unique, but can also have different names for the same app (one name for any language you want; it can be localizable)